# Dax measure to find and show parent values and self (self displays as blank())

Tags: parent-child, dax, measure

I have a table that has budget amounts at Level 2 and amounts at Level 1.  I have a slicer.  when I select a value in the slicer, I need my dax to find its parent and show these levels (and blank() at the Level1).  It is not a defined hierarchy, but I could make it one.

I am trying to produce the two results in the snip below.  One example with D selected in the slicer, the results to its right.  Second example is C...   I can got my select value measure to work, but need help with "Budget $" measure
[image]

I am trying to write a budget measure that produces the results above.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want the values from the Budget rows. Something like this:

```
Budget $ =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Value] ), Data[Type] = "Budget" )
```

This should replace the current type context (D or C in your example) with Budget.

Comment: in the first example, your suggestion returns Budget for "Little" and "Big" or a Grand Total of $25.  In that example I would want to exclude the "Big" budget amount of 10. When I select "D", I need to see if it belongs to little or Big, then get the Budget Amount.  And finally hide it at the lowest level (which I know how to do) .    In actuality my real data, has dozens of variations of ("Big", "Little") so it shows allot of budget items i don't need.  Thanks

Comment: Try adding the argument `Data[Size] IN VALUES ( Data[Size] )` to the CALCULATE. Does that change the behavior to what you expect?